# how to correctly record the counting of averages between the minimum and maximum of the matrix on fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I was trying to write a program to calculate the average without considering the minimum and average of the columns, what is the best way to do this? To begin with, I wanted to simply output the average value of the columns to a file, there are no errors, but nothing is output.

```
Program Matrix
 Implicit None
Real,Allocatable,dimension(:,:)::A 
Real,Allocatable,dimension(:):: b 
Integer varStr,varStlb 
Integer i, j  
real summa
Open(1,file='in.txt') 
Open(8,file='out.txt') 
Do 
read(*,*)varStr,varStlb
Allocate(A(1:varStr,1:varStlb),B(1:varStlb)) 
Read(1,*) ( A(i,:), i = 1,varStr )
do j = 1, varStlb           
   summa = 0
   do i = 1, varStr
     summa = summa + a(j,i) 
   end do
   b(j) = summa/varStr       
   write(8,'(A,F8.2,A)')'b = ',b(j), ' - сумма всех элементов' 
 end do 
Deallocate(A)
Enddo
End Program Matrix
```

in file is

```
10.05   -22.0   3.0
4.0 0.0 60.0
8.0 13.0    22.5
```

Comment: Welcome, it is good to ask in steps. And ask one question in one post. One question: Why nothing is prented by my code? Completely different question: How do I compute what I need to compute? Try to foces always on one problem.

Comment: Besides, I do not understand the description of what you jeed to compute. What are these columns? What does the average between the minimum and maximum mean?

Comment: Regarding the output: Do not forget to close your files using `close()`. I highly suggest avoiding unit numbers below 10, they are often pre-connected to things like standard input and output.

Comment: means to display the average value of the column, ignore the minimum and maximum, display them separately @VladimirF

Comment: **How** ignore maximum and minimum? You want to exclude the maximum and minimum values when computing the average? Why? I simply do not get it. If yes, then just subtract the minimum and the maximum value from the sum and divide by *n-2*.

Comment: What is the input for `read(*,*)varStr,varStlb`.  If `varStlb` isn't given a positive value then not much will happen.  We need a _complete_ example (see [mre]) to be able to help you.

Comment: @francescalus sorry, but i cant send a complete example because i dont have them, varStr, varStlb its a N and M(column and row) matrix.

Comment: @VladimirF yes, i need exclude the maximum and minimum, its my assignment at the university, but we were not given any guidance on how to do this in Fortran.

Comment: The use of a mask could make sense here. SUM, MINVAL, MAXVAL, MAXLOC etc all can accept a MASK, so one can easily eliminate the inner loop. Either do the SUM and remove MAXVAL and MINVAL (Like @VladimirF suggests), or use a mask and set MINLOC and MAXLOC to false and the rest of the mask to true, and SUM(A(i,:), MASK=mymask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote, there are too many points in your question. Therefore it is hard to make an answer, that covers your question well and does not give you just a solution to your homework without real understanding of the problem.

You have many problems or strange points in your code

1. I do not see the reason for the outer `Do` loop. In this loop you will try to read from the file many times. There is no protection to read past the end of the file.
2. When reading from the file you always `allocate` your arrays. But you never `deallocate` them In the next iteration of the outer `Do` loop you try to allocate them again, but that is not allowed, they are allocated already.
   Perhaps you just wanted to read the whole file just once?
3. I always suggest to learn in steps. First read the file as you need it, print it, verify that it is in the form you needed. Only than compute normal averages. Only then compute averages that exclude maximum and minimum.
4. Ignoring the maximum and the minimum is simple, just subtract them from the sum and decrease the count of the elements by 2. However, as the rest of your code is so chaotic, it is impossible to just add it there. I will just show a sketch of the procedure:

Normal average of array `a(1:n)`:

```
avg = sum(a) / n
```

Average of all elements except the maximum and the minimum:

```
avg2 = (sum(a) - minval(a) - maxval(a)) / (n - 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, @VladimirF. I using Do loop for average a column.